# Android Market - the only crash reports I get are on Platforms "OTHER"

Tags: android, crash, google-play, platform

I've an app in the market with a few crash reports of "java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made". This is covered elsewhere on SO and I know where in my code it is. That's not my problem - the problem is finding out which Android version and handset type is causing it. I've never seen this on any handsets the app is tested on, nor does any version of Android on the emulators raise it. The only crash errors I see are these and always on "Platforms OTHER". I'm assuming if a different crash was reported I'd get a better clue regarding the platform - I'd expect to see "8", "11" etc.

It's a paid app. It happens right on first run so the users are cancelling the purchase.

Does anyone know what this platform is please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the developer console reports very few of the crashes occurring in your app.

If your app already requests internet permission you can use an error reporting library.

I use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) in my app. It's very easy to integrate and you'll be amazed at the number of crashes that don't get reported in the market developer console.

Comment: blazeroni has a good answer too but Mircea actually offers a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Platforms section displays the device the crash occurs on, not API level.  However, as you've seen, it's very limited.  The only values I've seen besides OTHER are

- T-Mobile myTouch 3G
- Nexus One
- Droid

Anything else is lumped in with OTHER.  Obviously, the list of devices it separates out is vastly incomplete and not very helpful.  Until Google improves it, the Platforms sections is essentially useless and I recommend using a third party library to get better information.